# onClick is ignored when an input is focused and virtual keyboard is visible

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, mobile-safari

In my react app noticed that onClick handlers are not invoked on Android and iOS browsers until the virtual keyboard is visible. Only "touchStart" works. So first we need to hide the keyboard and only then the onClick handlers start work. And it seems like this is ok behavior. But I could not find any proof of it. Could you drop me a link that I can use as proof?

Comment: I doubt what you're saying here is normally true. I don't see what a virtual keyboard has to do with whether or not an onClick will fire or not. Sounds unlikely. Maybe other code is blocking it or maybe the onClick is being wired up after you think it is in code.

Comment: You are right. Just created a sandbox to test and I see that on click works fine even with the opened keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you are are not "wiring up" the eventhandler until after the virtual keyboard is displayed. You probably just need to move the code where "the onclick is being wired to a function" outside of its current scope (so that it happens sooner than the virtual keyboard is being displayed).

For example, maybe the onclick isn't being set until after an event that indirectly leads to the virtual keyboard being displayed (like another onclick event).

Comment: Fixed. I had a problem with animation. I'm doing a custom unfocus animation with :after element. During which I'm changing the z-index of :after element. So, the element simply overlapped my buttons.

Comment: Ah, so it was firing, you just couldn't see it because it was happening behind something else. I see. Glad you figured it out.